# Set GitKraken to track a directory on a remote server as local repo

Tags: git, gitkraken

I am using GitKraken to track a remote GitHub repo accessible via ssh and that works fine, but I want to switch the local repo that GitKraken tracks to the directory I currently use for development that is placed in a Linux server (also accessible via ssh). Apparently, there is no obvious way to do that, do you know a way? I'm open to use another Git GUI if Kraken doesn't allow this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using GitKraken to track a remote GitHub repo accessible via ssh and that works fine

One thing to clarify here is that GitKraken cloned the GitHub repo as a local copy. It really only "tracks" the local clone. It then allows you to interact with the GitHub remote with specific commands like `git push` and `git fetch`.

If you want to also interact with a remote linux server that you have access to, you will need to set up [a git server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server). Then you can add a remote to your repository in GitKraken that points to the linux server that you set up.

To understand this better, I suggest reading about [so-called "remotes" in git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

Comment: I think what GitKraken does is clear to me, my question is whether I can make it track another local repo after it copied the remote repo on my machine. In addition to that, I want the local repo to be tracked to be a directory on the server, I don't want to set the directory on the server as a remote repo (hence I am pretty sure I don't need to set up any git server nor doing anything about the remote).
I assume what I want to do can be achieved "primitively" by just periodically copy-pasting the directory on my server to the directory GitKraken tracks as local, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: @user9870949 If the linux server is available as a network share, then you can use the `\\shareName\path\to\repo` syntax that Windows supports. Or if it is mounted to a local linux file system, you can use the path where it is mounted. These both look like "local files" to the operating system, so GitKraken will be able to use them. Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is, as I said, adding multiple remotes to your local repository that you already have configured in GitKraken.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first two options are not viable for me. I'll probably explore the possibility to use a git server to do something similar to what I need. Thanks!